# How do I make text as big as possible in a container if I don't know what the text is?

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have a container (width 100%, height 100%, so it fills the screen, if that matters). I have a bit of text, but I don't know what it is; it could be a single word or a few lines. Is it possible to use pure CSS to set the font-size to something so that the text could be as big as possible without wrapping, overflowing, or having the user scroll? If not, what's the easiest way to do so using JS?

Because I don't know what the text is, I can't use `vw` or `vh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a jQuery plugin that can do the job easily for you, it's called [FitText](http://fittextjs.com).
A sample script will look like this.

```
`jQuery("h1").fitText(0.38);`
```

You can check the [source](https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/) for more solutions than jQuery.

Comment: Thank you. I used one of the plugins you mentioned in the source (namely textFit)